# how to replace annotations with file configuration (with XML) in spring boot project

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I'm looking for replacing the annotation (@Entity , @Table , @Id , @GenratedValue , ...) of JPA and hibernate with a configuration file (also the queries in repositories files), but I don't know how to do it , what I know is that I need another (other than application.properties ) file of configuration in XML format , my question is where I do create this file ? and what its content ?

---

thank you so much for responding me.

now my project looks like this :
[spring boot project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hq3Bs.png)

and this is my orm.xml file :

```
<entity-mappings>
    <entity class="org.sid.dao.entity.Etudiant">
        <table name="etudiants">
            <attributes>
                <id name="id">
                    <genrated-value strategy="AUTO"></genrated-value>
                </id>
                <basic name="nom"></basic>
                <basic name="prenom"></basic>
                <many-to-one>
                    <Join-column name="id_formation">
                        <basic name="formation"></basic>
                    </Join-column>
                </many-to-one>
            </attributes>
        </table>
    </entity>
    <entity class="org.sid.dao.entity.Formation">
        <table name="formations">
            <attributes>
                <id name="id">
                    <genrated-value strategy="AUTO"></genrated-value>
                </id>
                <basic name="nom"></basic>
                <basic name="duree"></basic>
                <one-to-many mappedby="formation" fetch="lazy">
                    <basic name="etudiants"></basic>
                </one-to-many>
            </attributes>
        </table>
    </entity>
</entity-mappings>
```

but the JPA won't create the table in the database, what I should do ?

Comment: Any specific reason why you want to do thisk when you already use Spring Boot?

Comment: Please don't do this.

Comment: I want just to know a new method to do it, also when we separate configuration from the class that looks easy to maintain after, there is anyone know how to do it?

Comment: JPA documentation is widely available, and some give the equivalent XML example for annotations, like this one http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_1/jpa/mapping.html

Answer (score 0):

The JPA specifications requires the XML mappings to be located on the class path:

> An object/relational mapping XML file named orm.xml may be specified
>   in the META-INF directory in the root of the persistence unit or in
>   the META-INF directory of any jar file referenced by the
>   persistence.xml.
>
> Alternatively, or in addition, one or more mapping files may be
>   referenced by the mapping-file elements of the persistence-unit
>   element. These mapping files may be present anywhere on the class
>   path. — Section 8.2.1.6.2 of the JPA 2.1 Specification

Have a look at the Hibernate documentation:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#bootstrap-jpa-xml-files

Comment: the problem is: there isn't a directory called META-INF in spring-boot project I know that there is a directory called META-INF in JAR or WAR file, but the orm.xml file is called at build time, there is no way to copy the file in META-INF directory after generation of JAR/WAR , so what i can do now ?? and thank you for responding.

Comment: Just add this directory in src/main/resources thats all